# StripeClient.PaymentRequest doesn't seem to exist, is the documentation out of date?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am following the Xamarin Stripe documentation [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/stripe).

All fine until I get to this:

```
var paymentRequest = StripeClient.PaymentRequest (
                        "merchant.com.{your_app_name}",
                        new NSDecimalNumber ("10.00"),
                        "USD",
                        "Premium llama food");
```

That method just doesn't seem to exist. I have encountered cases of Xamarin documentation being out of date in the past, is this another instance?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to use the Stripe's `iOS` Apple Pay api, you will want to look at Stripe's Android SDK regarding Android Pay/Google Wallet, creating a `Charge`, etc...

Comment: Ah, this was the only code in the article for taking payment, assumed it would be the same for Android or iOS

Comment: Ah, There are platform differences in the SDKs, I used the Stripe.com SDK docs and translate from ObjC/Swift to Java to C# ... Personal preference I guess, I tend to go straight to the source... ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover Good advice, thanks!